# performSegueWithIdentifier pushes two ViewControllers when pressed 2x fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a complex app when I sometimes need to use *performSegueWithIdentifier*. I can't replace this with IB triggers, must be done programatically! Sometimes I call them in UIButton's actions or even in delegate methods as *collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)*

The problem is that if I trigger the events twice and fast, for example by double tapping an UIButton, I get the destinationViewController pushed twice into the navigationController's stack, which is not what I want. I only want it to be pushed once. prepareforSegue gets call twice as well.

Example:

```
func addDeal(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueDeal", sender: sender)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "segueDeal") {
        (segue.destinationViewController as! DealVC).deal = self.deal
    }
}
```

Comment: remove objective c from the tag as your question involves only swift language

Comment: What are you doing in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: It's irrelevant for me if it's swift or Objective-C. I just want an elegant way of doing it

Comment: @Paulw11 added `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the button when this method is called, this will prevent it from being tapped multiple times.

```
func addDeal(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    sender.enabled = false
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueAddDeal", sender: sender)
}
```

You will also have to re-enable it when your view re-appears **for example**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    someReferenceToTheButton.enabled = true
}
```

**Hair-Brained Alternative**

I've just knocked this together in a sample project as a "more generic way" as [requested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967428/performseguewithidentifier-pushes-two-viewcontrollers-when-pressed-2x-fast/32967574?noredirect=1#comment53760517_32967574). It "works" in the basic use case as shown but I honestly have no idea if it will work in more complex situations. I'm also not particularly happy with it, feels hacky and fragile.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var preparingForSegue = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        preparingForSegue = false
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func pushOn(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Provided as an example of an attempt to perform 2 segues in quick succession
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DoPush", sender: self)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DoPush", sender: self)
    }

    override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if !preparingForSegue {
            super.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: sender)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
        preparingForSegue = true
    }

}
```

Comment: That will work for sure but I was looking for a more generic way of preventing this behaviour without having to disable/enable the buttons in every viewController I do this

Comment: @Jdmoreira check my updated answer, use with caution though :)

Comment: I like it! I'll try it soon. Should work pretty well in all use cases! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this method was helpful:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  for window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
    if let window = window as? UIWindow {
      if let sub = window.subviews.first as? UIAlertView {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return navigationController?.topViewController == self
}
```

I just move this method to RootViewController, from which every controller in my main hierarchy was inherit. Notice that in method I'm also check if there is `UIAlertView` presenting.

Comment: @Jdmoreira, it check if top controller in stack is the same as controller that try to perform segue. This method called before controller perform some segue and you can specify if it should or shouldn't be performed

Comment: That's a great solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

better to delete **TouchUp Inside** on Button.